# Convergence in distribution of a product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, exponential-distribution

I'm kinda lost in this kind of problems, so I apologize if this is to easy.

Let $V_n\sim\operatorname{Exp}(n)$. I've already prove that $V_n \rightarrow 1$ in **probability**, $e^{-V_n}\rightarrow 1$ in **probability** but I cant manage to prove that $nV_{n}\rightarrow V$ in **distribution** where $V\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

Hope you guys could help, thanks so much in advance. :)

Comment: You probably mean $V_n\to 0$ in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P\{V_n >t\}=e^{-nt}$ by definition of exponential distribution. Hence $P\{nV_n >t\}=P\{V_n >\frac t n\}=e^{-t}=P\{V>t\}$.  This means $nV_n$ has the same distribution as $V$ for every $n$. Surely, $nV_n \to V$ in distribution.